# Word to call someone who is talented in the arts?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a call word to describe someone who is talented in not one, but *all* the arts? (eg. singing, painting, writing, etc.) The only words I can think of are *virtuoso*, *artist*, and *maestro*, but they all seem to have to do with only one of the arts. Example sentence: I love Jeffrey! He's a true [word].

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests

Comment: (Give us an example sentence.  It's not clear whether you want an noun or an adjective.)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "artist", though you could use, eg, "virtuoso".  Any single word you use, though, will carry a connotation, so if you want to make it clear you should use a multi-word term like "master of all the arts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not precisely what you're looking for, the closest you're going to get is [**Renaissance man**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Renaissance%20man):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : a person who has wide interests and is expert in several areas

So:

> I love Jeffrey! He's a true *Renaissance man*.

As I mentioned, the noun itself doesn't mean *arts* specifically, so you'd have to qualify the statement if you wanted to make that clear:

> I love Jeffrey! When it comes to the arts, he's a true *Renaissance man*.

Even that wouldn't necessarily mean *every* art, but it would certainly imply many of them.

---

If you are referring to a woman, and don't like the use of *man* in the noun, there is also [*Renaissance woman*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Renaissance%20woman). (I suppose you could coin *Renaissance person* if you wanted to be truly gender neutral. Although that has no definition, nobody would misunderstand its use.)

Comment: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/renaissance_man

Comment: vuomo univerasale in the Italian, I believe